# ListJoin and multiselect with criteriaquery with Polymorphism

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I was wondering if anyone knows the cause of the Exception being thrown? I have the following entities below. Is it because some Employees returned aren't DriverEmployees and thus do not have routes?

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class DriverEmployee extends Employee {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Routes> routes;
}

@Entity
public class Routes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String description;
}

CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Employee> employee = criteria.from(Employee.class);
Root<DriverEmployee> driverEmployee = criteriaBuilder.treat(employee, DriverEmployee.class);
ListJoin<DriverEmployee, Routes> routes = driverEmployee.joinList("routes");

// Want routes to be returned as a list in the multiselect.
criteria.multiselect(employee.get("name").alias("name"), routes.alias("routes"));

TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(criteria);

query.getResultList().forEach((t) -> {
    process(t.get("name", String.class));
    processList(t.get("routes", List.class).size());
});
```

The error I'm receiving is below. Anyone know how I can get the following to run successfully?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'routes' {originalText=routes}
```

Comment: I assume that it's not possible to select a collection within a multiselect. In this case, routes is a one-to-many List<Routes>.

Answer (score 1):

In this current example you have tuple which contains one object of DriverEmployee and one object of Routes (I recommend you to rename this entity to Route and set @Table(name = "routes"). According to JavaDoc of `multiselect()`:

> If the type of the criteria query is CriteriaQuery (i.e., a criteria query object created by either the createTupleQuery method or by passing a Tuple class argument to the createQuery method), a Tuple object corresponding to the arguments of the multiselect method, in the specified order, will be instantiated and returned for each row that results from the query execution.

So it means that you CAN'T make a Tuple like `Tuple<DriverEmployee, List<Routes>>`
The way how you can reach such behavior of your current query is to do it by yourself. For instance:

your method with criteria:

```
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Tuple.class);
Root<Employee> employee = criteria.from(Employee.class);
Root<DriverEmployee> driverEmployee = criteriaBuilder.treat(employee, DriverEmployee.class);
ListJoin<DriverEmployee, Routes> routes = driverEmployee.joinList("routes");

criteria.multiselect(employee.get("name").alias("name"), routes.alias("routes"));

TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createQuery(criteria);

List<Tuple> resultList = query.getResultList();
Map<String, List<Routes>> resultMap = getMapFromResultList(resultList);
resultMap.entrySet().forEach((name, routesList) -> {
            process(name);
            processList(routesList);
        });
```

and the method of obtaining the map:

```
private Map<String, List<Routes>> getMapFromResultList(List<Tuple> tuples) {
    Map<String, List<Routes>> map = new HashMap<>();
    tuples.forEach(tuple -> {
        String name = tuple.get("name", String.class);
        Routes routes = tuple.get("routes", Routes.class);

        map.computeIfPresent(name, (key, value) -> {
            value.add(routes);
            return value;
        });

        map.computeIfAbsent(name, (key) -> {
            List<Routes> routesList = new ArrayList<>();
            routesList.add(routes);
            return routesList;
        });
    });
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the Hibernate JPA Criteria implememtation doesn't support that. If you really want to use the JPA Criteria API to do this, you are probably out of luck. In JPQL/HQL you could model this like `SELECT e.name, r FROM DriverEmployee e LEFT JOIN e.routes r`. On top of that you have to extract the values like Andrew Kolesnyk mentioned.

However, this is is the perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

Blaze-Persitence is a query builder on top of JPA which supports many of the advanced DBMS features on top of the JPA model. I created Entity Views on top of it to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(DriverEmployee.class)
interface EmployeeDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
    List<RoutesDto> getRoutes();
}
@EntityView(Routes.class)
interface RoutesDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EmployeeDto dto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EmployeeDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features and it can also be saved back. Here a sample repository

```
@Repository
interface EmployeeRepository {
  EmployeeDto findOne(Long id);
}
```

It will only fetch the mappings that you tell it to fetch.

Here you can see an example project: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/tree/master/examples/spring-data-webmvc